# if statement that always executes

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web application which is using a template (Smart Admin 1.3) and came across a strange block of code.

```
if (!null) {
  $('nav ul').jarvismenu({
    accordion: true,
    speed: $.menu_speed,
    closedSign: '<em class="fa fa-expand-o"></em>',
    openedSign: '<em class="fa fa-collapse-o"></em>'
  });
} else {
  alert("Error - menu anchor does not exist");
}
```

Is there any situation where the if-block would not execute?  Is this a strange javascript convention?

Comment: It looks to me like someone dummied out some code.

Comment: it's the equivalent of removing the if statement, without the side effect of not being able to go back if you don't have version control. (if you don't have version control, get version control.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a convention that the community would accept.  See @Niet's conjecture as to why someone would develop in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way this block would ever evaluate as *false*. '!null' will ALWAYS evaluate to true. Therefore the else statement in this if-else block is completely useless.

Since this would never evaluate to *false* the *if* part of the block will always be executed.

To answer your second question, no, this is not some strange Javascript convention.